# How to open a silverlight web application as light window?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I created simple Silverlight Application using the web site host of the VS2010 ( default ) feature.

Now, I want to make the Silverlight Application to be shown as light window in the front of the default web site.

How can  i do it ?

Comment: when you say "light window," do you mean you want the Silverlight app to appear in front of the HTML content as if it were in a jQuery lightbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go [OoB](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/out-of-browser-applications).

If you just wanted to show a modal dialog, then use the [`ChildWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx) or [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox%28VS.95%29.aspx).

I think you could also remove the website from your solution and the Silverlight project will still open in the browser.

I am not so sure about what you mean by "Light Window", but I am sure these links will help you a lot:

- [Integrating Silverlight with a Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145%28VS.95%29.aspx)
- [How to: Add Silverlight to a Web Page by Using HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28VS.95%29.aspx)

**Update**
If you checkout the web-host project, you'll see, that there is a test page that actually hosts the Silverlight project.
You can modify this page and move the Silverlight content around wherever necessary, or you might even embed it in a master page and/or use an external ASP.NET UserControl that will be used to load/host the Silverlight object dynamically.

Comment: OK, So how can i define it as childwindow on the ASP.Net side ?

Comment: @ינשוף What exactly are you trying to do, what do you mean by "light window"?

Comment: i dont want to remove the website. i want to have the website but open the silverlight app as lightbox

Comment: @שימי lightbox is like ChildWindow of the silverlight.